# Generate a data declaration with TemplateHaskell

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

I wonder how to generate a bunch of constants based on a list of names.

I started with this working example:

`ConstantCreation.hs`

```
module ConstantCreation where

import Language.Haskell.TH

createConstant :: String -> Q [Dec]
createConstant constantName = do constantType   <- newName constantName
                                 constant       <- newName constantName
                                 return [ DataD []
                                          constantType []
                                          [NormalC constant []]
                                          []                       ]
```

`MyConstants.hs`

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module MyConstants where

import ConstantCreation

$(do constantsDeclarations <- mapM createConstant
                                       [ "MyFirstCustomConstant"  ,
                                         "MySecondCustomConstant"   ]
     return $ mconcat constantsDeclarations)
```

But things get tricky when I try to add a `deriving Show`.

I first tried changing the function `createConstant` like this:

```
createConstant constantName = do constantType   <- newName constantName
                                 constant       <- newName constantName
                                 return [ DataD []
                                          constantType []
                                          [NormalC constant []]
                                          [GHC.Show.Show]          ]
```

as suggested if I run the command `runQ [d|data MyConstant = MyConstant deriving Show|]` in GHCi, but it throws the error `Not in scope: data constructor ‘GHC.Show.Show’`

So I tried do define my function like this :

```
createConstant constantName = [d|data $(ConT $ newName constantName) = $(NormalC (newName constantName) []) deriving Show|]
```

but then I had the following error:

```
Cannot parse data constructor in a data/newtype declaration: $(NormalC
                                                                 (newName constantName) [])
```

It would really be a pitty to have to define Show instances by hand, so I wonder what's going badly.

Thanks for any advice or explanation.

Comment: What is `eleveConstr` ?

Comment: What is `GHC.Show.Show`? You probably want the TH splice representing the name - `''Show` or `showCon <- mkName "Show"`

Comment: @Sibi I corrected the code. I changed the original code to self document the example, but forgot that.

Comment: @user2407038 I'll try it tonight. Looks that it will fix the first definition! But I still don't understand the problem with the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `''Show` to get the `Type` with the name that is in scope.

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

module Constant where

import Language.Haskell.TH

createConstant constantName = do
    tname <- newName constantName
    cname <- newName constantName
    return [DataD [] tname [] [NormalC cname []] [''Show]]
```